# XML conventions in Android Manifest - no closing tag for <action>

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, android-manifest

Just curious - why is there no closing end tag for  or < category > in the XML code below

```
  <activity
        android:name=".WidgetActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

The XML Schema of the AndroidManifest file allows empty-elements. An element with no content is said to be empty. The representation of an empty element is either a start-tag immediately followed by an end-tag, or an empty-element tag. 
For example the following are equivalent:

```
<br></br>
<br/>
```